# How to change button appearance in a jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc

When I click on a link in my jsp

```
<a id="ajout_lien" href="javascript:submitFormAjout()" class="under">go </a>
```

I call a javascript function

```
function submitFormAjout() {
document.forms['constitutionForm'].submit();
}
```

Then there is the jquery call to prevent from a double submit :

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(this).submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I change the appearance of my link while the submit is done (the real one, in the Jquery's call)? By instance change the color and label of my  tag ( let's say from "go" to "waiting"?
I want it to be as generic as possible : if, in another jsp of my application, the submit is made on a button, not a link, I an use 3 parameters : newClass (css) , idElement (of the button or the link) and label if it's a link.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
function submitFormAjout() {
    document.getElementById("ajout_lien").className ="over";
    document.forms['constitutionForm'].submit();
}
```

[jQuery .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ensures submit event is triggered only once.

```
$("form").one("submit", function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(this).submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't explain my goal clearly : I want to change the appearance of my link while the submission of the form. There is 2 problem : I want to prevent a double submission and I want to change the appearance while the real submission is done. Then the first appearance must be back. With your solution or Kurenai's one there is still the problem during the second submission.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
function submitFormAjout() { 
    $("#"+ (this).attr("id")).addClass("over");
    $('form[name="constitutionForm"]').submit();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="ajout_lien" href="javascript:submitFormAjout()" class="under">text </a>
```

If you want className to be dynamic, then you can pass it as function parameter and use that value in the method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't explain my need clearly so I edit my question. With your solution I have the same problem than with Pugazh's one : there is still the problem of appearance during the second submission.